# Sprite won't render by setting .GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a tower defense game, but my sprite doesn't render when I run the code shown below.

I first made two public colors and named them `startColor` and `endColor`

```
public Color startColor;
public Color endColor;
```

Then at the end of the code I made the `startTile` and the `endTile`(`startTile` and `endTile` are just variables for my sprites that start the path and end the path). I then tell my code to get the renderer and `.color` to change the color to `startcolor` and `endcolor` but it just the changed colors and doesn't actually render

```
startTile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = startColor;
endTile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = endColor;
```

no error messages
if u need more context my yt is RFG game dev and just join my discord
pls help

Comment: does the colors you assing have alpha? Maybe you just render them transparent by accident?

Comment: are you doing this in the `void OnGUI()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the alpha channel is not at 0.

[image]